# Difference between echoing using quotes and without

Tags: bash, shell, diff

I saved output of `diff` to variable `variable=$(diff file1 file2)`

When printing using `echo "$variable"`, there appears text with new lines:

```
1c1
< x
---
> y
```

but when using `echo $variable`, everything stays in one line.

```
1c1 < x --- > y
```

I wonder what is a reason of this difference.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution to your query is at: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/124638/41427

Compare

```
$ echo $(printf 'foo\nbar\nquux\n*')
foo bar quux ssh-13yzvBMwVYgn ssh-3JIxkphQ07Ei ssh-6YC5dbnk1wOc 

with

$ echo "$(printf 'foo\nbar\nquux\n*')"
foo
bar
quux
*
```

Again quoting:

> Without quotes the string is subject to [word
>   splitting](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/WordSplitting) and
>   [globbing](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob) . See also [BashPitfalls #14](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#echo_.24foo).